Determining the Change of Basis Matrix for Given Bases in R^3
Question:
Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^3$  be a 2-dimensional subspace with two bases $ A = (a_1, a_2) $ and $ B = (b_1, b_2) $ 
Given that $ b_2 = 2a_1 - a_2 $ 
which of the following matrices can represent the change of basis matrix $ [I_V]_B^A $?
(a) \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
(b) \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}
(c) \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
(d) \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
The answer should be a) but I dont understand why. It makes sense to me that the second column of the matrix should be
\begin{pmatrix}  2 \\  -1 \end{pmatrix}
Can someone explain? Thank you. (sorry for formatting, new to latex).

The two columns of $[I_V]_B^A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ are the coordinates in $B$ of the two vectors $a_1,a_2$ (and not the converse), hence the coordinates in $A$ of $b_1,b_2$ are
$$\frac1{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}*&2\\*&-1\end{pmatrix},$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}-b&=2\Delta\\a&=-\Delta\\\Delta&=ad-bc,\end{cases}$$
hence
$$\begin{cases}b&=2a\\1&=-d+2c.\end{cases}$$
